# Image Sensors Tint Issue

Tags: image-sensor

I have a problem about color CMOS analog NTSC image sensor. I use OV7955 image sensor and I connected to the monitor. Monitor displays like this:

[image]

I tried anathor lens and view doesn't change. I thought the problems is related with connectors, I soldered the connections of image sensor again and the output view is like the first picture. How can I solve this problem?

In once, image was cleared like that:

[image]

I don't have any idea, this is how happened. Is there a connection problem are hardware problem? After that I suspended connections but connections are true. I soldered again, renew the connections but view was never changed.

In below, there are some stuff on the camera

[image]

[image]

Green marker's colour on the display is purple. Multimeter's colour is totally green. This is my what I use lens:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome.  It would be very helpful if you say what you consider wrong with the image: we don't know what it it is supposed to look like.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add. The view must be clear. This image has green/purple tint. Even if I tried another lens, view doesn't change. I don't understand why.

Comment: Hi ... perhaps you could take another photo (with your phone, perhaps), to show us what the correct colours are like.

Comment: What settings are you using? Please note that the data sheet says the video signal compatibility cannot ne guaranteed with all displays. Have you tried to output the colourbar test signal? Have you tried different displays?

Comment: @Justme I don't think, displays has a problem, because I tried another image sensors with this displays and it's works. I have only one displays and haven't tried colour bar test.  Actually, In once view was cleared on the displays and I thought problem is related with cables or connections but even if I soldered again and checked the connections, view wasn't change.

Comment: This looks less like a tint problem and more like a complete failure of the red channel - can you place some coloured artifacts in the scene and see if the red ones come out black? This specific camera could be broken.

Comment: If the lens has an "auto-iris" feature, then if the brightness of the scene increased, it would have reduced the aperture automatically, which would have improve the chromatic aberration.

Comment: Can you show a picture of the lens?

Comment: @Bryan I added to questions.

Comment: @colintd I added lens too

Comment: This was closed due to being about repairing consumer electronics, which is clearly not the case.

Comment: @Justme Actually, I asked the producer but they don't know the problem. There is a hardware problem but I can't find that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem related to hardware but I solve this. When I decrease voltage supply to 3.1V, view is cleared like below.

[image]

Thank you for your attentions and helping.

Comment: What may be the reason behind that? A missing line termination resistor?

Comment: Actually, I would expect the image sensor work in 5V but it's works 3.1 -3.0V. I sent the producer this issue and I'll give you feedback.

Comment: @Jens sorry for late reply. They don't know the reason behind that. I decided to create a new PCB design for this, maybe my hardware design might be wrong, Idk but producer said there is no issue hardware design. Weird event.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the internal data path is incorrectly configured before video arrives to the NTSC video encoder.

The colourspace may be wrong, but unlikely as the brightness seems to go approximately correct.

The colours are clearly wrong, and the first image with green/pink would indicate that Cb and Cr colour signals are both mistakenly fed with either Cb or Cr.

The last picture with red things being shown as green would also indicate Cb being fed to Cr and Cb.

Try different settings as clearly the settings you are using won't work. Try getting the NTSC colourbar signal working first, but first figure out if the colourbar video data is generated before or after the video format and colourspace conversion block.

Comment: 100% agree that the new images are not due to lens issues.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Cb/Cr are swapped. Check your decoder sequence configuration. It could be that your active window is off by one pixel.

Normal BT.656 4:2:2 order should be, from left: Cb Y Cr (Y), where the first three co-sited on one pixel. If your window lands on the second pixel instead of the first you would see this swap.

Try using a color bars test image. Find one on the web (search for 'color bars') and put it up on our laptop. The normal colors will be white, yellow, cyan, green, magenta, red, blue, black.

Comment: It does not look like Cb and Cr are swapped. Red would have Cr positive and Cb negative, but red turns into green, which has both Cb and Cr negative. If Cb and Cr were swapped, red would turn into blue and blue would turn into red. Also green colour turns into pink, and shades of green would anyway have Cb and/or Cr negative, and pink would require both of Cr and Cb be positive. So I think this isn't a simple case of Cb and Cr being swapped.

Answer (score 1):

To me, the coloured fringes look like [chromatic aberration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_aberration) from a poorly corrected lens, as opposed to an electrical issue.

The basic version with uncorrected lenses gives red/blue fringes.  With a poorly corrected achromats, the red and blue points are right, but the areas either side (purple and green) aren't.  This is why green/purple is now one of the most common chromatic defects (see an example [here](https://lightroomkillertips.com/remove-purple-andor-green-fringe-chromatic-aberrations-lightroom/)).

It is caused by the lens bending different colours of light by different amounts.  The normal resolution is to use multiple different elements in the lens to provide what is called an "achromat".

A higher quality, better corrected lens should help, but in the meantime [reduce the aperture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_down) (close down the iris), if present, as this will decrease the impact of the edges of the lens (where the aberration is largest).

Comment: I don't think that's how chromatic aberration should look. It looks more like digital colourspace conversion or encoding problem. Maybe Cb and Cr are swapped?

Comment: @Justme Could be, but the tint is just at the edges and green / purple fringes are very common with poorly implemented achromats, where the red and blue points are corrected, but the regions inside/outside these points aren't.  Have a look at this less extreme example https://lightroomkillertips.com/remove-purple-andor-green-fringe-chromatic-aberrations-lightroom/

Comment: W.r.t. ``bit in the meantime stop down the aperture``, I'm not sure what _stop down_ means. Is that a typo?

Comment: Reducing the lens aperture is know as "stopping down", with the reducer known as a "stop".  IIRC this is because it "stops" the light through the lens.  This is also known as an "iris" or "aperture" control.  Make this smaller, and the quality of the image should improve.

Comment: @ChesterGillon [Stopping down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_down)

Comment: @ChesterGillon Thanks.  I've added that link to the answer

Comment: @colintd Either it is a serious case of chromatic aberration, or just data path to NTSC video encoder is incorrectly configured, because it looks like YCbCr but only Y working and Cb and Cr being equal, and in YCbCr, the Cb equals Cr axis is pink for positive C and green for negative C.

Comment: I also think the new images where all red items are green cannot be due to chromatic aberration.

Comment: @Justme 100% agree.  This problems with the later images are not lens related.